# Does integrating an update into ROM remove the older application version?

Tags: rooting, updates, partitions, system

I have a phone with very limited storage capacity, so I opted for integrating some updates into the system partition, the problem is that it quickly ran out of space in that partition too.

So, I'm wondering whether the previous versions are also kept somewhere and how to remove them. I'm using this [tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flaki.systemappmanager) to do the update integration, and it seems at some point to be doing a backup of something, I guess it's the user's data but I'm not sure.

Comment: The old versions are removed (overwritten actually)... Remember that changes version in the /system partition could cause your device to be rendered unusable if you perform a factory reset at a later date.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for the heads up, it already happened to me with this phone, I guess I'll need to keep a stock ROM image at hand before trying a factory reset again, just in case.